# Place footer at the end of page. Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to place footer at the end of my page (wheh there is a few text). Thus I added **h-100** to container

```
<div class="container h-100" style="margin:40px;"> <!-- wrapper for all containers -->
```

But when I have a lot of data on the page, footer intersects this data.
How can I fix it?
Example on the picture (black line is a footer)
[image]

**My code**

```
{% extends 'vacancy_list/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container h-100" style="margin:40px;"> <!-- wrapper for all containers -->
    {% for vacancy in vacancies %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h1><a href="#">{{vacancy.title}}</a></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                    <p> 40000 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="white-space:normal">
            <p> Описание вакансии: Компания Sixhands, занимающаяся разработкой мобильных приложений и веб-порталов в Санкт-Петербурге, ищет Backend-разработчика для создания серверной части мобильных приложений.
        </div>


    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div> <!-- wrapper end -->

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you please more describe that you want your footer where your content ends? or where the viewport ends

Comment: @ibnelaiq, I want footer at the end of page

Comment: @alcoder.I just answer your question below..(Dummy Text is your content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code helped me

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    #page-content {
      flex: 1 0 auto;
    }

    #sticky-footer {
      flex-shrink: none;
    }


    body {
      background: #007bff;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #0062E6, #33AEFF);
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div id="page-content">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <p> TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer id="sticky-footer" class="py-4 bg-dark text-white-50">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <small>Copyright &copy; Your Website</small>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are in need of a sticky footer. One way to accomplish this is by turning the entire page into a Flexbox:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: yellow;
}

main {
  background: pink;
}

footer {
  background: lightblue;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>
<main>MAIN</main>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Comment: he doesn't want to make sticky footer instead he wants to make footer where his text or content ends...Your solution is good but can't be more helpful in his problem.

Comment: @ibnelaiq That's what a sticky footer does. It appears at the bottom of the viewport, unless the text content overflows the viewport, in which case it appears at the end of the text content.